# How to redirect subdomain to specific subfolder AND rewrite url?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Trying to set up a subdomain.

I have `jonr.co` Working well so far. it goes to a `/var/www/jonr.co` in apache.

I'm trying to set up `promoter.jonr.co` to go to `/var/www/meetjon-dev` with the following url: `http://XX.YYY.ZZZ.AAA/meetjon-dev/index.php/promoters`

That actually work fine.

Problem is I need to keep the url to promoter.jonr.co so when I go to, say `promoter.jonr.co/dashboard` it goes to `http://XX.YYY.ZZZ.AAA/meetjon-dev/index.php/promoters/dashboard` but keep URL to `promoter.jonr.co/dashboard`

Also when I go to `promoter.jonr.co/eventManagement/review/123` it should go to `http://XX.YYY.ZZZ.AAA/meetjon-dev/index.php/promoters/eventManagement/review/123 and keep url (in the browser url bar) to`promoter.jonr.co/eventManagement/review/123` in the browser

Otherwise, I can't have my Facebook login working as it doesn't work with IP addresses (and IP addresses are ugly).

So doing the following in my .htaccess does redirect `promoter.jonr.co` to `http://XX.YYY.ZZZ.AAA/meetjon-dev/index.php/promoters` but then the url changes so I'm half way through.

What should I add to my .htaccess to do so ? (hatches is in /var/www)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^promoter.jonr.co
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://XX.YYY.ZZZ.AAA/meetjon-dev/index.php/promoters [L,NC,QSA]
```

Many Thanks for your time.

Comment: I think its actually better to do the first part (to redirect to folder) in http.conf file to redirect to the correct folder? Not sure tho

Comment: You will have to proxy the rewrite if you want to do it that way. If you use a `different` domain in the substitution string apache will do a redirect. No way around that. You can try and use the P flag. `http://XX.YYY.ZZZ.AAA/meetjon-dev/index.php/promoters [P]`